# Where can I find one link for a new entrant to the EOS platform to begin using the platform to develop apps?

Tags: documentation

I am new to EOS.IO. Where is the one link I can go to that gives me all the tools I need to develop an app?

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of this question: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/43/where-can-i-find-complete-whole-stack-eos-dapp-development-example-projects-w