# Where can I find complete (whole stack) EOS dApp development example projects? With smart-contracts, the necessary C++ coding and a browser interface?

Tags: development, dapp

I can't wait to find complete EOS.io dApp examples. Not only the WASM and Smart Contract, but the complete stack with f.e. the web interface.

Please add any EOS dApp Example project as answers on this question :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check out the Scatter Demos page which has both C++ contracts and a javascript front-end integrated with `eosjs` and `Scatter`. It was also just updated to match `master` branch for EOSIO as of 5-9-2018

http://demos.scatter-eos.com

And the code for it (including the invaders contract) here: 
https://github.com/EOSEssentials/Scatter-Demos

Comment: lol how I could forget this one!

Answer (score 34):

While there is limited information on dApp stack, here's what I found on the internet so far while we wait for more.

[Find the updated version of the compilation here](https://www.notion.so/aisle/EOSIO-Resources-b1eebd80eb494ddf8c9f9e4e7a25fa2b)

## Youtube Channels

1. [**nsjames**](https://www.youtube.com/user/grandmoren1)

   - Setting up a Virtual Machine and EOSIO for smart contract development
   - Basic EOSIO smart contract schema, structs, actions and persisting to the blockchain
   - Diving deeper into EOSIO Smart Contracts: Typedefs, Assertions and Singletons
2. [**Filip Martinsson**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyZyNVYEN-54HPYkVVHnRTA/videos)

   - Set up a local testnet
   - Smart contract programming tutorial
3. [**JD3**](https://www.youtube.com/user/magicmanxpress/videos)

   - The Linux of Blockchains
   - How to create a wallet and account
   - Intro to EOS programming
   - Using EOS with Node.js
   - Create a smart contract on EOS
4. [**EOSPHERE**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCROdE4_4xJ8p5K7d9k8G_Eg/videos)

   - Building EOS development environment from source
   - How to setup and run EOSIO genesis snapshot
   - Role of EOS block producer
5. [**EOS Canada**](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoTHlEOVdeN9NOc5b5C1-vQ)

   - How block producers will get voted in
   - Opinion on block producer hardware
6. **[E](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClgHiX4W1yxyohrif0gEllA)OS [- Educational Series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClgHiX4W1yxyohrif0gEllA)**

   - EOS educational series

---

## Articles

- Ian Grigg

  [EOS - An Introduction.pdf](https://www.notion.so/file/https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsecure.notion-static.com%2Fb06a7f47-ddce-414f-9ec9-be2b06e126df%2FEOS-AnIntroduction.pdf)
- Multicoin Capital

  [EOS Analysis and Valuation.pdf](https://www.notion.so/file/https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsecure.notion-static.com%2F25dc406c-29eb-4727-b905-9dd07290df7e%2FEOSAnalysisandValuation.pdf)
- [Unlocking the EOSIO blockchain by Thomas Cox](https://medium.com/@thomas.cox_39839/magic-15-unlocking-the-eosio-blockchain-91ec54f7b48d)
- [The ultimate end-to-end EOS dApp development tutorial by](https://infinitexlabs.com/eos-development-tutorial-part-1/) I[nfinitexlabs](https://infinitexlabs.com/eos-development-tutorial-part-1/)

---

## Tutorials & Webinars

- [Building apps with EOS by Kevin Heifner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Tx2DseLGE)

---

## Videos, Podcasts & Interviews

1. [EOS Go](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0fwWI2RBBtEIYIP6fH68XQ)
2. [Everything EOS by ICO Alert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG0KVnbMd7Y)
3. [EOS - The Decentralized Operating System by Dan Larimer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eftctVXiFJQ&t=1389s)
4. [Future of EOS & Crypto by Dan Larimer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7HQlcl-LlQ&t=9s)
5. [Introduction to blockchain by Dan Larimer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYAktmG1NuA)

Comment: the link to "EOS - An introduction.pdf" comes up with "Unauthorized".

Comment: Amazing overview of available resources. Thank you so much 

Comment: Here you go @Vlad http://iang.org/papers/EOS_An_Introduction-BLACK-EDITION.pdf

Comment: Here I am starting build a curated list of eos's resources towards developers.    https://github.com/eosplace/awesome-eos/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 12):

I'm writing here the contracts that helped me the most and the guides that I'm aware.

nsjames youtube series: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_0j3NAYVBiyY152K0f-2og

Kevin Heifner, Webinar from OCI, one of the main EOS committers: https://objectcomputing.com/resources/events/webinars/building-apps-with-eos/webinar-recording - the bonus here is that he teaches you how to **setup the CLion IDE and Unit Tests for contracts**!

Hack-Til-Dawn EOS Hackathon smart contract:

- Contract - https://github.com/nsjames/Hack-Til-Dawn
- Front-end https://github.com/nsjames/scatter-hackathon

Everipedia Whitepaper is perfect to understand a complete well designed dAPP: https://github.com/EveripediaNetwork/Everipedia/blob/master/TechnicalWhitepaper110.md

And of course, the default smart contracts that's inside EOS main repo: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts - try to rewrite the `eosio.token`, then go for `dice` - learned, a lot from them.

Comment: Taking off the RIDL ones. They are unrelated. The airdrop is an ethereum/solidity contract.

Comment: ah ok got it, so RIDL contract is only to manage the identities across the chains right?

Answer (score 7):

[Youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYIjxG00tv4) for creating and interacting with smart contracts for dawn 3.0, it doesn't include a web interface but seems quite in-depth otherwise with 3 videos available in the series.

[Non-video guide](https://infinitexlabs.com/first-steps-in-eos-blockchain-development/) for creating smart contracts, multi-part, as of this posting the guide is not yet complete with only 2 entries. The guide claims to be end-to-end so they may include a web interface portion.

Answer (score 5):

I made some example code that includes a simple smart contract and a web interface. There is a simple html/js/jquery version of the interface and a react version [here on github](https://github.com/rawrat/eos-poc)