# EOSJS tutorials

Tags: development, javascript, eosjs

I have checked [Where can I find complete (whole stack) EOS dApp development example projects? With smart-contracts, the necessary C++ coding and a browser interface?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/43/where-can-i-find-complete-whole-stack-eos-dapp-development-example-projects-w) But I haven't found a full EOSJS tutorials and documentations that would help me.

From the smart contract aspect the examples are great but from the web interface, there is alot missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best examples lives in Scatter-Demo repository: https://github.com/EOSEssentials/Scatter-Demos

I have also built MonsterEOS where you can check another interaction with EOSJS and Scatter: https://github.com/leordev/monstereos

Answer (score 1):

The basic EOSJS documentation is found on the [GitHub-Page](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs)

Unfortunately I haven't found any tutorials yet, but here is another good overview for general Information as [awesome list](https://github.com/EOS-Nation/Awesome-EOS).

I guess some knowledge about [NodeJS](https://medium.com/quick-code/the-best-tutorials-to-learn-node-js-34818d757013), [ES6](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/make-your-code-cleaner-shorter-and-easier-to-read-es6-tips-and-tricks-afd4ce25977c) and [Docker](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-easy-as-build-run-done-e174cc452599) would be good as well.

Comment: is docker needed, can't i run eos on linux normally?

Comment: Sure you can run it normally on linux. But personally I think it's easier to maintain and less to configure with docker.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link https://chaince.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010333093-Preferred-article-The-Big-List-of-EOS-Developer-Resources-by-Steve-Floyd that contains a lot of EOS tutorials and resources. I think that you will find them useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Zendesk link is broken but the article is available on Medium at https://medium.com/eostribe/the-big-list-of-eos-developer-resources-1f64e05464b9.

Answer (score 0):

i found new udemy course it's free it's about making a game using c++ and eosjs

[Elemental Battles: Learn how to build your first blockchain based game on EOSIO software](https://www.udemy.com/course/eos-blockchain-dapp-development-tutorial/)