# Do you know any useful links to help you develop DApp?

Tags: dapp

I've gathered links to help you develop DApp. I want more.

Comment: I've made a post of some links you may or may not like to add:
https://steemit.com/eos/@natp/ultimate-eos-developer-link-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gathered links to help you develop DApp.

**Developer Portal and ...**

https://developers.eos.io/

https://www.eosdocs.io/

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki

https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation

**Articles**

EOS 101: Getting started with EOS

https://hackernoon.com/eos-101-getting-started-with-eos-part-1-ab0324c233e0

https://hackernoon.com/eos-101-getting-started-with-eos-part-2-2afbce4a8a05

The ultimate end-to-end EOS dApp development tutorial — Part 1

https://infinitexlabs.com/eos-development-tutorial-part-1/

The Ultimate End-to-End EOS dApp Tutorial – Part 2

https://trybe.one/the-ultimate-end-to-end-eos-dapp-tutorial-part-2/

EOS smart contracts

Part 1: Getting started (Ping equivalent in EOS)

https://steemit.com/devs/@eos-asia/eos-smart-contracts-part-1-getting-started-ping-equivalent-in-eos

Part 2: Building a To-do list with EOS

https://steemit.com/eos/@eos-asia/part-2-building-a-to-do-list-with-eos-or-working-with-persistent-data-in-eos

Your first EOS dApp — The Contract

https://medium.com/coinmonks/your-first-eos-dapp-the-contract-ce793f43d852

EOSIO Multisig Tutorial

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-multisig-tutorial

**Ricardian**

https://steemkr.com/eos/@tanishqyeverma/what-are-ricardian-contracts 


**Related Question**
[Where can I find complete (whole stack) EOS dApp development example projects? With smart-contracts, the necessary C++ coding and a browser interface?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/43/where-can-i-find-complete-whole-stack-eos-dapp-development-example-projects-w)

**Curated list**
github.com/EOS-Nation/Awesome-EOS

Answer (score 2):

related question:

**BP List:**

[Where can I find a list of the current 21 Block Producers?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1099/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-the-current-21-block-producers)

**Premium Account:**

[Difference btw Premium + Non-Premium Accounts?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/991/difference-btw-premium-non-premium-accounts)

[Premium Eos Name Bidding time in UTC](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/premium-eos-name-bidding-time-in-utc)

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-premium-name-auctions-get-in-early

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/name-bidding-and-premium-names-on-eos

https://medium.com/@MediShares/q-a-eos-account-name-bidding-90890e72c92b

**Table data encryption:**

https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1096/1519

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/unittests/dice_tests.cpp

https://steemit.com/steem/@dantheman/how-to-encrypt-a-memo-when-transferring-steem

Answer (score 1):

**EOS Network Monitor**

EOS Network Monitor(+ RPC API Test) - by CryptoLions

http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/

**eos-rpc-api-example**

https://github.com/kristieguo/eos-rpc-api-example

**How to Air Drop**

https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSDrops https://github.com/grogn/airdropExamples/tree/master/EOS/contracts

Answer (score 1):

**Videos**

01 – Setting up a Virtual Machine and EOSIO for smart contract development

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glB6UPHo1rA

02 – Basic EOSIO smart contract schema, structs, actions and persisting to the blockchain

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z6XLyOOjIY

03 – Diving deeper into EOSIO Smart Contracts: Typedefs, Assertions and Singletons

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbWDHrm2ETY

Building Distributed Apps With EOS.IO Blockchain

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Tx2DseLGE

**EOS and C++**

https://www.youtube.com/user/jackodwhacko/featured

Answer (score 1):

There's also a full course on BitDegree.

[Blockchain Programming: Mastering dApp Development on EOS Blockchain](https://www.bitdegree.org/course/blockchain-programming)