# Difference btw Premium + Non-Premium Accounts?

Tags: account-name, premium

What's the difference between premium and non premium account names?

Is there bidding on regular account names (what is that process)?

Say I want the account name "java". That would be premium, no? How about if I want "java00000000" (12 characters)? Is that a non-premium account? How can I secure that account name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Normal acccount names

Are exactly 12 characters long and do not contain a dot. These can be created right now by sending a `newaccount` action to the [eosio.system contract](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.abi).

#### Premium Account Names

These are less than 12 characters or contain a dot. To obtain the right to create one of those with the `newaccount` action you must first win an [auction](https://eospark.com/MainNet/bidaccount) for that name. When you own the premium account `x` you and only you also gain the right to create accounts of the form `name.x`. Premium account names are basically your own TLD.

Answer (score 0):

Premium names will be available in the form of "suffixes".

The text of the link below answers your question.
https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-premium-name-auctions-get-in-early

Answer (score 0):

Also, I want to add that only one premium account suffix (or top-level-account name) will be released starting on the 14th day of main net launch. The highest bidder will get whatever suffix s/he bid for in a given day.

This means, if you bid for a premium name suffix with a low ball bid say 1 EOS or something, you may get it on a day when no other token holder has a higher bid (> 1 EOS) across all the names. This is really restricting and is originally designed to stop name squatting (like we have experienced in domain name arena).

However, I really hope that the community will vote for a workers proposal to allow changing this to 10-100 suffixes per day.  :)