# Can i add any pre-suffix to the premium account name that are currently bidding?

Tags: account-name

The premium account name bidding name has already taken place. And I see for example "com" is bidding now at 19 eos. So what is the difference between com and .(com) in EOS main net? If i bid "com" successfully , can i add any pre-suffix to it, like xyz.com, abc.com, 111.com?

Comment: You may be able to find your answer here: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/991/difference-btw-premium-non-premium-accounts or here https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-premium-name-auctions-get-in-early

Comment: Here is a similar question. It would be nice to delete your question if it is not much different. related question: Difference btw Premium + Non-Premium Accounts? Please refer to the links below. https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-premium-name-auctions-get-in-early https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/name-bidding-and-premium-names-on-eos https://medium.com/@MediShares/q-a-eos-account-name-bidding-90890e72c92b