# Premium Eos Name Bidding time in UTC

Tags: staking

Can anyone tell me what time exactly for the eos premium name bidding first round ends in UTC time and date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### June 28th 17:39 UTC [(Math)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=14%20Jun%2017:39%20UTC%20%2B%2014%20days)

---

According to EOS Authority, [the exact Birthdate of EOS is 14 Jun 17:39 UTC](https://eosauthority.com/timeline). I then added 14 days to that

[image]

Comment: 14 Jun 17:39 UTC + 14(days) = 28 Jun 17:39, Right?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=14+Jun+17:39+UTC+%2B+14+days

Comment: Thanks and do you know are there any time period limit for bidding the premium name during the 24 hour? Can i bid on the last 2-5mins?

Comment: I would have to examine the code to be sure, but I would assume yes.

Comment: The founder of GenerEOS said due to a bug, the bidding would start from 5th July. Can you confirm about it ? Thanks

Comment: Nope.  There's probably an issue on the EOS github for it if you want to go search for it there.