# Questions about Premium account name

Tags: account-name

1. Premium Eos Name Bidding time in UTC
   Can anyone tell me what time exactly for the eos premium name bidding first round ends in UTC time and date?
2. Can i add any pre-suffix to the premium account name that are currently bidding?
   The premium account name bidding name has already taken place. And I see for example "com" is bidding now at 19 eos. So what is the difference between com and .(com) in EOS main net? If i bid "com" successfully , can i add any pre-suffix to it, like xyz.com, abc.com, 111.com?
3. How to operate after successfully bidding a premium account name?
   i want to bid for premium name but is worried about how to operate after a successfully bidding? Anyone with some idea about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Not sure about the exact date/time in UTC or any timezone. All we know it is suppose to start after 14 days of mainnet start.
2. If you win the bid for com, you can register any name using: [a-z1-5]{1,8}.com
3. Once you will a premium name suffix (same as traditional top-level-domain), you can register any name for the suffix and sell them or give them away. If you sell them you just set the owner PUBLIC key to recipient's PUBLIC key so they have full control over it. Of course, if you are giving them to your dApp users and want to retain control over you do not give them ownership authority.

Answer (score 0):

related question:

[Difference btw Premium + Non-Premium Accounts?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/991/difference-btw-premium-non-premium-accounts)

[Premium Eos Name Bidding time in UTC](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/premium-eos-name-bidding-time-in-utc)

Please refer to the links below.

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-premium-name-auctions-get-in-early

https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/name-bidding-and-premium-names-on-eos

https://medium.com/@MediShares/q-a-eos-account-name-bidding-90890e72c92b