# Where can I find a list of the current 21 Block Producers?

Tags: block-producer

Where online can I find a list of the current 21 Block Producers? And the 100 additional standby producers?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some sites for that:

http://eos-bp-votes.dapptools.info/s/api/block-producer-votes-stack-html/1/70

http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/

Answer (score 3):

```
cleos system listproducers -l 100
```

Cleos with limit option is 100 should list top 100 BPS

Answer (score 1):

https://eosnodes.privex.io/ has IP addresses and config file generator for use with nodeos